# c++ What's the output of this function?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, program-entry-point

the output of this program should be this:

Can anybody explain why the output of this main is:

F1/2 F2/3 F5/4 F0/1 F0/1 F0/1 F0/1 F0/1

K0/1 K0/1

K?/? K2/3 K1/2

can you explain how we get the last 2 lines ?
thanks

the constructor is initialize like this in fraction.h

```
Fraction(int n=0, int d=1);

 /* fraction.cpp */
#include "fraction.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Fraction::Fraction(int n, int d)
: numerateur(n)
{
dedominateur = d;
cout << "F" << n << '/' << d << ' ';
simplifier();
}
Fraction::~Fraction(){
    //cout<<"destructeur";
cout << "K"
<< numerateur << '/'
<< dedominateur << ' ';
numerateur = dedominateur = 0;
}
void Fraction::simplifier(){/*...*/}

  /* prog1.cpp */
#include <iostream>
#include "fraction.h"
using namespace std;
void test(Fraction a, Fraction& b){
Fraction* c = new Fraction(a);
a = b;
b = *c;
c = NULL;
cout<< "F";
return;
}
int main(){
Fraction f1(1,2), f2(2,3), f3(5,4);
Fraction* tab = new Fraction[5];
std::cout << std::endl;
test(f1, tab[2]);
test(tab[3], tab[4]);
f3 = tab[5];
std::cout << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output with a `K` obviously comes from the destructor. Two of them would be from the parameter `a` which is passed by value (copy) to `test`. The other three are the ones on the first line of `main`.

The objects created by `new` are never `delete`'d, so they are never destructed.

Comment: thanks. it's the part I miss. sorry for putting such a long code.